# Getting stock earnings date from yahoo finance

Tags: python, yahoo-finance

I am using python and the yahoo api to get next earnings date for specified individual stocks from yahoo finance. Following link is info about using yahoo_fin:   http://theautomatic.net/yahoo_fin-documentation/#get_next_earnings_date  Also pasted below is the python script I am using. It basically gets the ticker symbols from an excel sheet and returns the next earnings date for the ticker. It works fine if all the tickers in the list have a next earnings date. However, as soon as it hits a ticker in the list that has no next earnings date (i.e. shows as N/A  on yahoo finance page), the script throws up an error (also shown below. actually a link as I am apparently not allowed to attach images yet!) and ends the process. Would appreciate a solution or workaround to this problem please. Thank you.

```
import yahoo_fin.stock_info as si
import pandas as pd

import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book("StockScreener.xlsm")
ws1 = wb.sheets["Tickers"]

#code to get number of rows with data
rownum = 3
maxRow = 3

while (ws1.range('B'+str(rownum)).value != None):
    maxRow += 1
    rownum += 1

for ticker_row in range(3, maxRow):
    ticker_symbol = ws1.cells(ticker_row, 2).value
    tickerEarnings = si.get_next_earnings_date(ticker_symbol)
    print(ticker_symbol,tickerEarnings)
```

Image of print out when code is run:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJLcv.jpg)

Text of printout (if unable to view image) below, but not aligned well though:

```
IMGN 2021-11-04 12:30:00
CAN 2021-11-29 13:30:00
NRXP 2021-11-15 21:00:00
HIMS 2021-08-11 21:00:00
ENLC 2021-11-02 20:00:00
CLOV 2021-08-11 21:00:00
MRIN 2021-11-03 10:59:00
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kay\PycharmProjects\StockScreener\EarningsYahoo.py", line 19, in <module>
    tickerEarnings = si.get_next_earnings_date(ticker_symbol)
  File "C:\Users\Kay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\yahoo_fin\stock_info.py", line 823, in get_next_earnings_date
    temp = parsed_result['context']['dispatcher']['stores']['QuoteSummaryStore']['calendarEvents']['earnings']['earningsDate'][0]['raw']
IndexError: list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: the error clearly says indexerror : list index out of range meaning you are looping the list more than then length of the list.

Comment: first you should use `print()` before line which makes problem to see what you have in variables. It seems you use wrong value as index. maybe `earningsDate` doesn't have any values and you can't use `[0]` maybe you should use `try/except` to catch it and skip data.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: @VimalanE, don't think it's to do with range or looping the list, as I tried using just one symbol that I know has not next earnings date (i.e shows as N/A on yahoo finance site) and came up with exact same error. I tried print(si.get_next_earnings_date("DIDI")).

Comment: @furas, it was not my idea about the external link to image, but that of stackoverflow (says I am not allowed, maybe because I am a new poster, to insert/upload image directly in the question). Not sure what you mean by your statement "always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot,...". What I have put in the question is a copy of the full error message.

Comment: first: you should put text, not images. Second: At first moment I didn't see error (because it was not formatted) so I put my standard text about error. After reformatting your text I saw that there is full error.

Comment: it it not problem with your function `range()` in `for`-loop but with `[0]` which module uses to get data - and this is problem with `index range` in list, not with command `range()` And solution is to run line `get_next_earnings_date()` in `try/except` to catch error and skip data.

Answer (score 1):

As you said problem is that some symbols have no `earningsDate`.

When `get_next_earnings_date()` tries to get `['earningsDate'][0]['raw']` then it can't get `[0]` and this raise error `index range` because there is no element with index `0`.

It has nothing to do with your command `range()`.

Standard method is to use `try/except` to catch error and do something with this problem - ie. you can skip data for this symbol.

---

Minimal working example

```py
import yahoo_fin.stock_info as si

for ticker_symbol in ['IMGN', 'DIDI']:
    print('Symbol:', ticker_symbol)
    try:
        tickerEarnings = si.get_next_earnings_date(ticker_symbol)
        print('Earnings:', tickerEarnings)
    except Exception as ex:
        print('[Exception]', ex)
        print('Earnings: skiping this symbol')
```

Result:

```
Symbol: IMGN
Earnings: 2021-11-04 13:30:00
Symbol: DIDI
[Exception] list index out of range
Earnings: skiping this symbol
```

Comment: Works! Awesome! Many thanks for your assistance. very much appreciated!